# How to add CSS new 'content-visibility' property to a React class component that uses Typescript and SCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add this new released style property - (It's a new css property - you can read about it [here](https://web.dev/content-visibility/))

```
content-visibility: auto;
contain-intrinsic-size: 1000px;
```

to a div wrapping some content but getting errors that the property is unknown.
So far I've tried:

1. Adding it to the scss under the right class like so:

```
.capWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 108px;
  margin-top: 71px;

  content-visibility: auto;
  contain-intrinsic-size: 1000px; 
}
```

but getting an error:
`Unknown property: 'content-visibility'scss(unknownProperties)`

2. Adding it directly to the element as a style object:

```
render() {
    
    const contentVisibilityStyle = {
      contentVisibility: 'auto',
      containIntrinsicSize: '1000px' 
    } as React.CSSProperties;

    return (
      <div className={classes["capWrapper"]} style={{contentVisibilityStyle}}>
        some content
      </div>
```

But getting this error:

```
Type '{ contentVisibilityStyle: React.CSSProperties; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'contentVisibilityStyle' does not exist in type 'CSSProperties'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1437, 9): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'
```

Any ideas how to implement this property correctly would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What's giving you that error in option 1? Your SCSS compiler? Or is it just a warning from your linter or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened is that React+Typescript can't recognize the new CSS properties.
The build is failing because React is saying "I don't know what this is and can't process it".
Probably because the version of TS that you are using does not support them, or they are so new that TS did not added support for them yet.

You have a couple of options:

1. You can define by yourself those new CSS properties and extend the understand of TS by doing it in a d.ts file.
   This will make TS understand them and fail the build. And also this will give you intelisense for them in your future work.
2. You can bypass all of this by adding them in a simple CSS file and load ot of the app scope. For example directly in your index.html. This will make Typescript compiler or react or any other framework just to ignore it (as they don't know about it)

I suggest also checking if maybe someone released some NPM package that adds support for those new CSS properties to Typescript.

The first solution is more a "do it yourself". The second is more of a hacky way, but will definitely work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

You create a `css.d.ts` file with:

```
import * as CSS from "csstype";

declare module "csstype" {
  interface Properties {
    contentVisibility: "visible" | "auto" | "hidden";
  }
}
```

This works because `@types/react` depends on `csstype` for css.

https://github.com/frenic/csstype#what-should-i-do-when-i-get-type-errors